# Verify the following identity

Tags: combinatorics

Using mathematical induction, verify:

$${n \choose k} = \frac{n}{k} {n-1 \choose k-1}$$

For the base case, I need to have k=0? Or both n and k? When just k=0, there is a fraction with 0 as the denominator? The LHS is = 1, but I don't think this makes the RHS = 1...

Help?

Comment: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_rule with fix $k>0$

Comment: Induction is a fairly silly way to prove this identity; are you *required* to use it?

Comment: ${n \choose k} = \frac{n}{k} {n-1 \choose k-1}$ iff $k{n \choose k} = n {n-1 \choose k-1}$

Comment: Yes, it is required.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac nk{n-1\choose k-1}=\frac nk\frac{(n-1)!}{((n-1)-(k-1))!(k-1)!}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}={n\choose k}.$$